# App not running/opening after install from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 20.04, 22.04

I tried to build .deb files or application on ubuntu 20.04 using tauri, but when I try to install the .deb package from ubuntu 20.04 to install it on ubuntu 22.04, the result are successful to install, but after I'll open the app to run, it won't open or not running in the background process, how can I able to fix this? or is there a way I can compile/build from ubuntu 20.04 and run it on ubuntu 22.04?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is very confusing.

Comment: deb files are binary files. In order to build something for a different OS, you actually need the source files of the software. You can see what is wrong by running the application in a shell, most likely some dependencies are not satisfied or are incompatible.

Comment: @David when I try to install the .deb package in ubuntu 22.04 from ubuntu 20.04 (that is where I build the .deb file), it won't open the app after installing it.